# Procedure for licensing Android market

Tags: android, google-play, procedure

On the [Android Compatibility page](http://source.android.com/compatibility/index.html) it is stated that:

> Once you've built a compatible device,
>   you may wish to include Android Market
>   to provide your users access to the
>   third-party app ecosystem.
>   Unfortunately, for a variety of legal
>   and business reasons, we aren't able
>   to automatically license Android
>   Market to all compatible devices. To
>   inquire about access about Android
>   Market, you can contact us.

Does anybody know what the actual procedure is to get Android Market on you own device, assuming the [CDD](http://source.android.com/compatibility/overview.html) is followed and the [CTS](http://source.android.com/compatibility/cts-intro.html) is passed. Specifically I would like to hear from someone who have experience on licensing the Android Market?

Also, I hear that Google has relaxed the restrictions on licensing the Android Market after version 2.3, but I cannot find any sources supporting this statement. Does anybody have additional information on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's very easy, on the page you linked to (http://source.android.com/compatibility/index.html), there's a Contact Us link on the left side. You will find all the contacts information at http://source.android.com/compatibility/contact-us.html

Good luck!

Comment: Hi. Sorry if I did not make myself clear in the question. I understand that I should contact Google, but I am interested in what happens at that point. What is the procedure I have to go through? What will Google specifically require of me? Production samples?

Comment: That's a question for Google :)

Comment: Or a question for anybody else who have been trough the procedure already. Or anybody who knows about the process through other means.